# Linking to a post within Rails site from a Rails blog post produces posts/posts/article-name path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, blogs

I'm a pretty new developer ~1 year, and I built a blogging site in Rails.

I have a set up where if I click on a post from the home page it goes to www.example.com/posts/article-name.

I decided for my Contact and About Me pages I would just make them blog posts, and then link to them from the nav bar using this syntax in my layouts/_navbar.html.erb file:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to 'About', "posts/about-me", class: "nav-link #{yield(:about_active)}" %>
</li>
```

When I click on the About link from the Home page it works fine, taking me to www.example.com/posts/about-me

However, if I am inside of a blog article and I click on the About page it takes me to www.example.com/posts/posts/about-me

I'm a little lost on how to fix this. I tried even hard-coding the link but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you go through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something you need to understand about absolute and relative paths.

relative path is what you have tried.

try the absolute path

```
<%= link_to 'About', "/posts/about-me", class: "nav-link #{yield(:about_active)}" %>
```

Comment: Like Nithin suggested, you've forgotten the `/` at the start of your path which is making it relative. Doing that would fix your problems here. 
Better practice is to use rails path helpers instead of hardcoding your urls though.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't notice the preceding /. Thanks Nithin!